# Передача Лямбды C++ в С API

Tags: c++, c

Имею СИ API ассинхронное, которое требует передачи функций обратного вызова(вызов функций в отдельном потоке).
Допустимо объявить лямбду в требуемой сигнатуре на стеке и передать ее параметром в си вызов? Лямбда ничего не захватывает. Правильно ли я понимаю, что на адрес метода не влияет время жизни лямбды.
Для примера код:

C API:

```
typedef void ( *Callback_t )( uint8_t*, int );
int make_request(Callback_t clbck); // Колбек будет вызван в другом потоке и произвольное время
```

C++

```
class MyCWrapper {
    int request() {
        auto lambda = [](uint8_t* buf, int size) {
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                std::cout<< buf[i] << ','
            }
        };
        return make_request(lambda);
    }
};
```

Comment: В этом примере передается не лямбда, а указатель на функцию, в который она преображается. Если бы она что-то захватывал, то это бы не прокатило. Также она должна быть `noexcept`.

Comment: @user7860670 clang с вами не согласен https://cppinsights.io/s/18defa6f

Comment: Однако по вашей ссылке выходит, что согласен.

Comment: С-шное апи должно предоставлять дополнительный `void *` параметр для передачи произвольных данных в функцию - или напрямую как параметр функции, или через какую-то спрятанную переменную. Без этого лямбды поддержать невозможно (можно только лямбды без захвата).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Именно на это и расчет void* в реальном коде присутствует, для передачи контекста.

Comment: @user7860670 был не прав.